# sysread on an IO::Socket::SSL socket masks ERROR_SYSCALL, how to get an actual errno here?

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl

I've got a perl program using an IO::Socket::SSL, and if I yank the net when it's in a loop reading, the call to sysread, which eventually goes to _generic_read, which calls the SSL $read_func, errors with a errno 5 (gotten from Net::SSLeay::get_error in _skip_rw_error).  Except then _generic_read masks that off because it's $Net_SSLeay_ERROR_SYSCALL and treats it like an empty read, with a comment and if statement you can see here:

https://github.com/noxxi/p5-io-socket-ssl/blob/master/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm#L1133

My program gets pretty confused at that point, because the socket is dead but I can't figure out how to query on this.  $s->connected returns true because getpeername is still working (I assume because it hasn't timed out yet).

How do I get this sysread to fail with $! set correctly for the error?

I can call Net::SSLeay::get_error($socket->_get_ssl_object(),-1) in the debugger and it returns 5 as expected, but that's pretty sketch to use _get_ssl_object.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: The aim of IO::Socket::SSL is to look for the application similar to "normal" sockets. This means it will hide some openssl specific behavior from the application, like the ERROR_SYSCALL on some connection close (due to failure to properly send a SSL shutdown alert). In general - if read returns 0 the socket should be considered closed - `connected` and `peername` are the wrong indicator here even for non-SSL sockets. If this explanation does not help you please provide short code which shows what you are trying to achieve and what you get instead - so that one can help with this example.

Comment: Okay, that seems a little weird to me, since there was an error, not a normal clean close, but it appears you can't tell the difference without going internal?  I can modify my code to use returning 0 as an indicator to be done (or reconnect) it'd just be a lot cleaner to be able to tell the difference?

It's also a little odd that connected() isn't the right thing to call here, since it is, uh, not connected anymore.

Comment: (sigh comment rules...)
From perldoc sysread:  _Returns the number of bytes actually read, 0 at end of file, or undef if there was an error (in the latter case $! is also set)._

I get that it's trying to cover up the EOF error from the ssl lib, but it seems like it could have done a better job here in the case of an actual error?

Comment: *"It's also a little odd that connected() isn't the right thing to call here, since it is, uh, not connected anymore."* - From [IO::Socket::connected](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Socket#connected): *"...  Thus, in general, it cannot be used to reliably learn whether the peer has initiated a graceful shutdown because in most cases (see below) the local TCP state machine remains in CLOSE-WAIT __until the local application calls "shutdown" in IO::Socket or close. Only at that point does this function return undef.__ ..."*.

Comment: ah, okay, weird, but I missed that, thanks!  I got the program working with the "assume zero is done" and I just use the internal SSLeay error for debug output (it's always 5 in my case as expected), thanks for the help!